# Using different nav graphs in android

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I am using to manage screen with android navigation component and I have 2 different nav graphs. I have problem for move from one graph any screen to another graph any screen. These screens are not start destionation of 2 nav graphs. How can do it

I have one solution for this but this solution doesn't help me for this problem. This solution is that i use deep link but i don't find destionation app url and it doesn't work